# jquery - stack with accordion

Tags: jquery

I have **jquery, html, css** code found in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/tyeKJ/2/)

Someone know how to add active state, your reply is a great help.

```
$("#accordion > li").click(function(){

    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('#accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});

$('#accordion > ul:eq(0)').hide();
```

Comment: what do you mean by active state? do you wanna highlight the selected tab or something?

Comment: thank's for the reply sir, i want is, if the accordion is open the background color of #accordion "li" will change. you can visit my sample sir http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/tyeKJ/2/

Comment: thank you Bassam Mehanni with the great answer i have one concern sir. i want one tab will open default http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/tyeKJ/6/ when the tab show the color also change. thank's again sir your a reply is a great help.

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tq5Y8/ note that I initially turn off animation just so that the tab expand immediately the first time around

Comment: hi sir one more thing sir how to make it when i click it to close the accordion the color "http://jsfiddle.net/tq5Y8/" will back to normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a class to the clicked tab

css:

```
#accordion li.active {
    background: red;
}
```

javascript:

```
$("#accordion > li").click(function(){
    //remove the 'active' class from the currently selected tab
    $('.active').removeClass('active'); 

    //assign the active class to the tab that was just clicked
    $(this).addClass('active');

    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('#accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});

$('#accordion > ul:eq(0)').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZjBTk/

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `active` style it.. and add this(`active`) class to li when clicked.

try this...

**jquery**

```
$("#accordion > li").click(function(){
  $("#accordion > li").removeClass();
   $(this).addClass('active');
if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
    $('#accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
}
$(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});

$('#accordion > ul:eq(0)').hide();
```

**CSS**

```
#accordion li.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyeKJ/5/) here